# Excel Import of custom mandatory field doesn't work [Hybris 6.7.0]

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, backoffice, excel-import

I'm using Hybris version 6.7.0 and I stuck with the following problem:
When I trying to perform importing products from excel file. It gives me the following error ->
[image]

I've checked the excel file and there is, of course, field "Subscription Term*", it is mandatory that's why there is an asterisk there. Good to mention that this field is custom, so I write custom translator to it and exporting part works fine, but in importing part when I did debugging I found strange fact:
This *WorkbookMandatoryColumnsValidator* validator calls the method **findColumnIndex(typeSystemSheet, sheet, this.prepareSelectedAttribute(mandatoryField));** from *DefaultExcelTemplateService* this method returns -1 and the validation does not passed. I dig into this method and there is such line of code:
**String attributeDisplayName =  this.findAttributeDisplayNameInTypeSystemSheet(typeSystemSheet, selectedAttribute);** which returns "Subscription Term" string as you can see without an asterisk.
I've checked the other mandatory fields e.g. "Catalog version*^"  it returns with 2 symbols after it.
The thing is that "Subscription Term" and "Subscription Term*" after string equality operation returns false and the validation fails as you can see here: 
**attributeDisplayName.equals(this.getCellValue(headerRow.getCell(i)))**.
Of course the second value is taken from the excel file where the asterisk sign presents.
If I remove an asterisk from excel file then I receive: Unknown attributes of type ISku error in *WorkbookTypeCodeAndSelectedAttributeValidator* validator:
[image]

The asterisk should be presented in excel file, I've just checked what would be...
It doesn't help me at all to understand what really happens.

***I can't understand one thing: What is the source of "Subscription Term" string? Why without an asterisk? Is it predefined constant somewhere?***

From debug I couldn't figure out from which source that string comes from.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know for sure but I expect that string( i.e **Subscription Term**) to come from a localization file based on backoffice current session language ( e.g **{extensionName}-locales_en.properties** if the current language is en).

Try to search after "**Subscription Term**" in all properties files.

Maybe, if the attribute is mandatory(i.e **optional="false"** in items.xml) then Hybris will add to its name an "*" when performing the import.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you provided read and write permission to that attribute for that user.
Check with admin user before doing that. If there is no issue with admin user, then only permission issue with the user.